# How to access Model Values when using backpack fields on custom (non-CRUD) pages?

Tags: laravel-backpack

Based on the following link, we can use Laravel backpack fields on non-crud pages:

[How to access backpack fields on custom (non-CRUD) page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68041779/how-to-access-backpack-fields-on-custom-non-crud-page)

But what would be the correct way to pass model values to those?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

Welp. Had a look at the source and figured it out. :)

Might be handy for someone looking for it.

Attribute 'Value'.

```
$model=User::find(1);

$crud->addField([
    'name' => 'name',
    'label' => 'Name',
    'value' => $model->name
]);
```